# Recover Data from Session Timeout

Tags: magento-1.9

I've just spent the last 45 minutes entering new information into a magento 1.9 store admin specifically the pages section. I go to hit save, only to find that Magento has logged me out. I've lost the last 45 minutes of my progress, leaving me frustrated and annoyed.

Is there a way to find this data or have I got to write the information again?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem or need further assistance?

Comment: Thank you to all the people providing answers; no further assistance is required.

Comment: Great! I am glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the work you have done is lost, you will have to enter it again. I can recommend increasing the admin session timeout or save more regularly.

You can increase the admin session timeout using MySQL. Run this:

`select * from core_config_data where path like "%cookie%";`

You should find admin session:

[image: Screenshot from phpmyadmin showing the record found from the above query]

You can change the value of that field to anything you like, e.g. `86400` which would change the admin session to 24 hours (86400 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

Its lost as it was never saved anywhere.  You will have to enter it in again (save more regularly!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138213)

Comment: "Is there a way to find this data or have I got to write the information again?"  no there is no way to find this data.  is that not an answer?

Comment: PaddyD raises a good point. `The Information is lost` is a direct answer to the question asked. OP did not ask for any ways to over come this issue. Comments like yours @Rama is everything that is wrong with this community

Comment: @vmp and PaddyD answer, not exactly correct and it also is not a permanent solution.  barefeet provide a permanent solution.  session increase is also in Magento backend. I think I expected more from paddy :)

Comment: In my defence, he did not ask "how do you make your session last longer" he asked is the data lost, does he have to write the info again, the answer is yes and yes (so "exactly correct").  But yes Bare Feet is a better answer by also giving a tip on how to stop this from happening in the future, but the first line of his answer is the same as mine.

Comment: Thank you for the help with my question. I have found something called "Lazurus" which isn't related to Magento (It's an extension for Firefox)

Comment: @slvjoe  but don't you need to have had that install first before you can recover from it?

Comment: @PaddyD Unfortunately, I've typed out the information again. Thank you for your answer. (Yes, Lazurus only works if you've previously installed.)